# Unable to set CLASSPATH with confluent CLI : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to use JDBC connector on `confluent`. It doesnt work when I start connect with Confluent CLI.

```
confluent local start connect
```

and it gives this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.10:1954/MYSERVICE
```

---

I stop connect and start manually `connect-distributed` or standalone it gives same error

```
./bin/connect-distributed etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties
```

but [when I set `CLASSPATH`](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#no-suitable-driver-found) then above code is working fine and transfer data to Oracle.

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/my_confluent/confluent-5.4.1/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/ojdbc6.jar
```

---

But still I can not do same thing with `connect` service.

When I up my `confluent connect`

```
confluent local start connect
```

it gives same error.

Comment: Please add the log line that says `DEBUG Loading plugin urls` to your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution after many tries.

I copied `ojdbc6.jar` file into `/home/ersin/confluent-5.4.1/share/java/kafka/` folder and restart connect service and boom it works like a charm.

for your information

Comment: JDBC JAR files aren't read from here. What this did was put it on the `CLASSPATH`, which you could have also just `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/odbc6.jar && connect-distributed ...`

Comment: cricked it works like this and no mater how much you downgrade this answer  I will tick this correct answer !!!

Comment: "it works" is fine. I downvoted because it's not correct and you shouldn't be running Kafka Connect on the same servers as brokers, anyway

Comment: If I put that jar to that folder on all brokers so it works I guess

Comment: In the blog I linked to, it mentioned adjusting the log properties to DEBUG and seeing if the JAR is read... Did you put it in `share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc` and try that?

Comment: I meant did you actually read the logs? Did it **say** the driver was **attempted** to be read?

Comment: can you explain how can I put that and where

Comment: 1) Find the `log4j.properties` somewhere under `etc/kafka` 2) Update it to say DEBUG instead of INFO everywhere, then [`confluent local logs connect`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/command-reference/confluent-local/confluent_local_log.html#confluent-local-log) after you get the error you posted.

Comment: `[2020-04-02 10:01:48,212] INFO Attempting to open connection #1 to Oracle (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:92)
[2020-04-02 10:01:48,215] INFO Unable to connect to database on attempt 1/3. Will retry in 10000 ms. (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:99)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:`

Comment: That is the task log, not the connect server startup process

Comment: it is : **./bin/confluent local log connect** log

Comment: Yes, but there are more logs then just that one line. `confluent local log connect | grep DEBUG`

Answer (score 1):

The Confluent CLI uses Golang to start up scripts underneath, so that may explain why exporting Java specific variables do not work, however, given that if you `export CLASSPATH=/any/path/to/jdbc-drivers/*.jar`, then run *any* process in the same terminal process, it *should* inherit those variables.

`confluent local start connect` internally calls some `exec.command("connect-distributed"`) function, which thereby is a Java method call that is ran through [`kafka-run-class.sh`, which does inherit the `CLASSPATH` variable](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4.1/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L297-L300)

Comment: I ve set classpath vefore connect service but it doest not work

Comment: It's possible that golang could clear the environment or override the classpath, IDK. You would have to reach out to Confluent Support with that issue

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver needs to be within the same folder as the JDBC sink connector.

So if your JDBC sink connector (`kafka-connect-jdbc-5.4.1.jar`) is in `etc/kafka-connect-jdbc` then put `ojdbc6.jar` in that folder.

*Edit*: after placing the JDBC driver here you must restart the Kafka Connect worker.

I've written up and recorded details of this whole process here: https://rmoff.dev/fix-jdbc-driver

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer, my ojdbc6.jar and kafka-connect-jdbc-5.4.1.jar in the same folder (/home/ersin/confluent-5.4.1/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/)

Comment: What about if you use `ojdbc8.jar` ?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar I've editted this answer to include the note that you need to restart the worker. You have found an alternative approach that works in a sense by chance, but the canonical answer is the one that I've given here.